# ReferenceError: FB is not defined in Angular 5 Karma Unit Test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have this issue when I have karma unit test.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM97j.png)

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: FB is not defined

I have already added following script in index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

This is my `auth.service.ts` file.

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private fb: FacebookService
  ) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (this.token) this.isLoggedIn = true;
    else this.isLoggedIn = false;

    let initParams: InitParams = {
      appId: environment.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.8'
    };

    fb.init(initParams);
  }
```

When I am doing unit test, `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js` file is not loaded at all.

how can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This is script code which I added in index.html file.<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

Comment: is this script file added above the main JS file, i.e. this file should be added before making a call to the FB object.

Comment: Please add the error you get in your question. People do not often follow links to images.

Comment: Hello, Marcel50506 Thanks for your reply. This is error. Failed: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: FB is not defined

Comment: Hi, Lalit Sachdeva. Thanks for your reply. The JS file is added before </body> in index.html file.  But I think it is not working when I have unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** you need to load external javascript file into Karma testing env by adding `files` config in `karma.config.js` like following:

```
files: [
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
    ],
crossOriginAttribute: false,
```

**And then** make sure your test is performed **NOT IN** `async` mode.

So normally, testing is made in async mode like following:

```
it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Just remove `async`, so that it looks like following:

```
it('should create the app', (() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Hope this will solve your issue.